# delete activemq consumed message/s

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus, producer-consumer

I am using ActiveMQ in my app. My question is how to delete messages that ı consumed successfully from using ActiveMQ. Because if it is not deleted, my db.data file is growing up constantly, which is not an optimum solution.

Comment: what you tried? what's gone wrong? asking _how do I do something_ is not a good question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about persistent messages, once the consumer acknowlege a message, this is marked to be deleted. The actual message deletion from disk happens only when its journal's file is no more in use. You can find [more details here](https://activemq.apache.org/why-do-kahadb-log-files-remain-after-cleanup).

Journal files are not cleaned up if they are in use:

- Contains a pending message for a destination or durable topic subscription
- Contains ACKs for messages that are in the data files that are in use (journal chaining)
- References a pending transaction which can not be removed until the transaction completes
- Undergoing a pending write to that journal

If you see a build up of journal's files, in most cases, the cause of this is related to unacknowledged messages that have been routed to some type of DLQ. To free memory, consume/purge messages or delete unused durable subscriptions until the broker can clear up the journals.